# Shortest path in BST

Tags: algorithms, trees

Given a Binary Search Tree and two elements $e1$ and $e2$ which are in the tree, find the length of the shorted path between them. Give the representation of the Binary Search Tree(use a linked representation with dynamic allocation without an attribute for parent or height). Implement the required operation and specify its complexity. Hint: try to find first the Least Common Ancestor of the nodes, the first node which is an ancestor for both nodes.

I thought that for finding the Least Common Ancestor we have to make a preorder traversal for example having the while loop : $while(!(e_1<a == e_2 < a))$, but I don't know how to count the length between them.
How should I count them?

Comment: Please credit the source where you encountered this task.

Comment: What's your question?  This is a question-and-answer site, so we require you to articulate a specific question about your situation.  A question usually ends with a "?".  Please ask only one question per post.  I see several tasks in your problem statement.  Note that we're not really looking for questions that are a statement of an exercise-style task and a request for us to solve it for you.

Comment: I don't know the source, but I know a harder version of this problem here https://timus.online/problem.aspx?space=1&num=1471&locale=en

Answer (score 1):

There is a unique shortest path $P_T(u,v)$ between two nodes $u$ and $v$ in a tree $T$. Such a shortest path goes from $u$ to the lowest common ancestor (LCA) $z$ of $u$ and $v$ in $T$, and then goes from $z$ to $v$. Notice that it might be possible for $z$ to coincide with $u$ or $v$.

To find the length $d_T(u,v)$ of $P_T(u,v)$ is therefore sufficient to find the LCA $z$ of $u$ and $v$ in $T$.

There are several ways to do this. One straightforward way that requires time $O(n)$, where $n$ is the number of nodes of $T$, is the following:

- Initially all the vertices of $T$ are unmarked.
- Start from $u$ and iteratively walk towards the root of $T$. Mark all the encountered vertices.
- Start from $v$ and iteratively walk towards the root of $T$. The LCA of $u$
  and $v$ is the first marked vertex encountered during this walk.

An easy way to reduce the running time to $O(d_T(u,v))$ is that of alternating the steps of the walk from $u$ with those of the walk from $v$. Assume that $u \neq v$ (otherwise the answer is trivial) and do the following:

- Initially all the vertices of $T$ are unmarked except for $u$ and $v$.
- Let $p_u = u$, and $p_v = v$.
- Repeat the following:

  - If $p_u$ is not the root of $T$:

    - Move $p_u$ to its parent in $T$.
    - If $p_u$ is marked, return $p_u$ as the LCA of $u$ and $v$. Otherwise mark $p_u$.
  - If $p_v$ is not the root of $T$:

    - Move $p_v$ to its parent in $T$.
    - If $p_v$ is marked, return $p_v$ as the LCA of $u$ and $v$. Otherwise mark $p_v$.

Once the LCA $z$ of $u$ and $v$ is known, it takes time $O(d_T(u,v))$ to find the distances from $z$ to $u$ and from $z$ to $v$ in $T$. Therefore $d_T(u,v)$ can be found in time $O(d_T(u,v)) = O(n)$.

If you have to frequently report the distance between pairs of vertices in a static tree then you can do so in constant time per query after a linear time preprocessing:

- Build a LCA oracle: a data structure that can report the LCA between two vertces in $T$ in contant time. This data structure can be constructed in time $O(n)$. The construction is very clever and elegant. See [this paper](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007%2F10719839_9) for the details.
- Augment each node $v$ in the tree by storing its depth depth($v$) in $T$.
- Answer a query for the distance between $u$ and $v$ in $T$ by: 1) finding the LCA of $z$ of $u$ and $v$ using the oracle; 2) returning $(\text{depth}(u) - \text{depth}(z)) + (\text{depth}(u) - \text{depth}(z))$.